# How to add row numbering in crystal report C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have started creating reports using `crystal reports`. I am able to show everything using `dataset` and `sql` except for the `auto-row numbering`.

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection cnn;
string connectionString = null;
string sql = null;
connectionString = "data source=Kim; initial catalog=DBO;user id=sa; password=passw0rd";
cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cnn.Open();
sql = "select Name as DataColumn1, Age as DataColumn2,  from tbl1";
SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
cnn.Close();

DataSet2 ds = new DataSet2();
dscmd.Fill(ds, "DataTable2");

CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1 ();
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The Result of the report is like this:

```
No  Name    Age
    Kim     22
    Ian     29
    Aris    27
```

Need to show the report like this:

```
No  Name    Age
1   Kim     22
2   Ian     29
3   Aris    27
```

Can you give me idea on how to add row number.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a new 'Running Total Field'
2. Give a name for the field Like 'RowNo'
3. Choose a field to summarize
4. Set the 'Type of summary' to 'distinct count'
5. In 'Evaluate' choose 'For each record'
6. In 'Reset' choose 'Never'

   Click OK
   Add the field to the report.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `'RecordNumber'` **special field** would be the most simple and easy way to achieve it. Record Number Field is used to number each record printed in the Details section of your report.

Comment: that's what I did Srinivas. Sumeshk gave me an idea. Thanks.

Comment: But how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In crystal report their is option to add auto increment field,no need to fetch rownumber from database

Comment: Thank you for the Idea Sumeshk, i checked Crystal Report Features and added record number on the row. It's auto increment now. Thank you.

Comment: But how Sumeshk?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic sequential numbering in crystal report

1. Open Crystal report
2. Field Explorer, right-click "Running Total Fieids" - New
3. Configuration.

   3.1 Select Field to set (Choose a field to summarize)

   3.2 Click to select Custom Field values

   3.3 Select "Type of summary" to set ( 'Type of summary' to 'distinct count')

   3.4 Set "Evaluate"  (Set ‘for each record’)

   3.5 Set "Reset"(set ‘never’)

   3.6 Click OK.
4. Then add the field to report

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use datatable and take DS.tables[0].rows.count and take a count inside and which increments with every loop iteration.

```
    DataTable tab_lvl = new DataTable();
       tab_lvl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NO", typeof(string)));
       tab_lvl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
       tab_lvl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AGE", typeof(string)));
       tab_lvl.Columns.Add(newDataColumn("Allot_Asset_Code",typeof(string)));
int count;
        for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        count++;
        DataRow dr = tab_lvl.NewRow();
        dr["NO"] = count;
        dr["NAME"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLname/number"];
        dr["AGE"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["COLname/number"];
    }

//bind the datatable to the report
objRpt.SetDataSource(tab_lvl);
```

Comment: Thank you Ankur, I'll take note of the idea.

Comment: This is the simplest method!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the select query to

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Age) as No, Name, Age from tbl1
```

which will produce expected result.